# Can a multiple page PDF output be achieved with 2pages side by side from one merged xml in XSL_FO?

Tags: xsl-fo

We have a requirement to prepare a PDF output of different contents with different renditions.
We have a mergedXml where several xml contents gets merged to form one merged one,where based on the type of xml each topic xml will be having different rendition.
Now i want to get one assembled PDF preview where the cover page will be one single Portrait page and other contents will go side by side with different rendition.
What should be the best approach to start with,any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Notes:- We are using Renderx for PDF output.

XML Structure is something like this--

```
<map>
 <topicref>
   <topic type="Executive_quote">
    |
    |
   </topic>
   <topic type="Client_quote">
    |
    |
   </topic>
 </topicref>
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the content flows on for multiple pages with exec in column 1 and client in column 2 then you have a two column table. Create a simple table with two columns and put the content from each one in its own column.

Example:

```
 <fo:table>
       <fo:table-body>
               <fo:table-row>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                           <fo:block-container  margin-right="20pt">
                                <fo:block space-before="6pt">Manager: Elitr accumsan lorem vero eirmod tincidunt vel enim....</fo:block>
   <!-- and more and more content here for manager -->
                           </fo:block-container>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                      <fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:block-container margin-left="20pt">
                                <fo:block space-before="6pt">Customer: No elitr eu nib ... </fo:block>
    <!-- and more and more content here for customer -->
                           </fo:block-container>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
               </fo:table-body>
          </fo:table>
```

And of course, you can use this as a base. If you are writing a custom DITA template for this, the content area would be replaced with:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="topic[@type='Executive_quote']"/>
```

and

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="topic[@type='Client_quote']"/>
```

Results in (two page view to show the flow):

[image]

Comment: Hi @Kevin Brown, Thank you for your immediate response.Here i'ld like to brief you that one contentType goes in one page at one time & the other in the next page.This process continues till it gets the contentType.Previously we were able to achieve it by specifying multiple fo:layout-master-set page info & the content respectively for every page.
But we don't want all the code to be written in one single file rather we want for every content type there should be separate files with the logic & as of needed it will be pointing to specific xsl.ThankYou.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand without a visualization of what you desire. Your "words" are unclear. Are you saying ... fill page #1 with executive content, page #2 with client content, page #3 with additional executive content, page #4 with additional client content, and so on ... or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding,We have 2 requirements where we have to show individual content-types in a single PDF preview which we have already created, for this we have written single xsl-fo and showing in separate PDFs.Now again we need to combine all the content types and show them in a assembled PDF with two content in each page with a two page view.Can we reuse our existing xsl-fos as the individual content will look alike but only will come side by side.If we can reuse can you please suggest how we can achieve that?Thanks

Comment: Ok i will post a solution for you later. It is RenderX specific. Do you want the new document to be twice as wide or the pages shrunk to fit original size (and landscape).

Comment: Look here for inspiration, one would only need to modify how the pages are selected http://services.renderx.com/lists/xep-support/6124.html

Comment: Thanks kevin.For the first Question,none of these, both the contents will fit in a different page with different @height,@width as per the requirement.For the second i.e XEPOUT, how do we integrate this with java and XSL-FO?Could you please suggest how do we approach?
Thanks

Comment: The xsl changes the size, remove that part and set new page size to 2x input size. There are many ways to integrate in java, I suggest you continue this through RenderX support and I will help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments clarifying the issue, here's another solution. As I understand it, what you really desire is two *pages* side by side as one page. If you look here, you will find a CoolTool post I did at the RenderX web site.

http://www.xportability.com/CoolTools/n-up.zip

Inside that zip file are samples of n-up processing of RenderX's Intermediate format.

While this example does page 1 and page 2 into page 1, page 3 and page 4 into page 2 .... you can easily modify this. You would format into one document executive followed by client. Then using this approach, just change the way it goes through the file and do page 1 and page 11 as page 1, page 2 and page 12 as page 2 ...

Below is he sample output from the tool as is.

[image]